# Does Magento 2 follow the PSR2 or Zend standard?

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

I am testing my extension code against the **PSR2** and **Zend** standards. However, the two standards conflict. I found a problem which I fixed for Zend, which then showed as an error in PSR2. If I fix it for PSR2 it will show as error for Zend. Which is the preferred standard for Magento 2?

> Zend Error:: Opening brace should be on a new line
>
> PSR2 Error:: Whitespace found at end of line

The same goes for `_`:

> PSR2 ::Property name "$_productLoader" should not be prefixed with an
>   underscore to indicate visibility
>
> Zend ::underscore to indicate visibility Protected member variable "productLoader" must contain a leading underscore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento 2 follows PSR2 [(Source)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html), I found some pieces in the core code are still breaking the rules set by PSR2 but I suppose that's mostly older legacy code which has not been refactored yet. Custom code written today, however, should always be written following the [PSR1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) guidelines.

Comment: TiEul is correct in that we follow PSR1 & PSR2 which can be referenced in our devdocs: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html

Comment: Correct, there are some examples of PSR2 noncompliance, though these should all be marked in docblocks. PRs are welcome!

Comment: Also worth noting that Magento 2 observes PSR-3 & PSR-4 as well. Note that [Magento is a member of FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/members/), the organization behind PSRs.